Whether the following is Z-estimator/M-estimator?
As I understand it, a Z-estimator is defined by the following equation:
$$ E(f(Y; \theta)) = 0 $$
where $ f(Y; \theta) $ is a function such that its expectation with respect to the true distribution equals zero. The empirical version of this estimator, based on observed data, is given by:
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(Y_i; \hat{\theta}) = 0 $$
I am now curious whether the following form can also define a Z-estimator:
$$ E(m(Y; \theta)) E(f(Y; \theta)) = 0 $$
where $m(Y; \theta)$ and $f(Y; \theta)$ are functions of $Y $ and $\theta$. Is this formulation consistent with the concept of a Z-estimator? Or what is estimator for it

Leaving labels aside, finding a population relation in expected value value terms that includes the data and the unknown parameters, and the use the correspondence between expected values and sample means to estimate the parameters is a widely used method under different names and approaches.
So in principle any kind of such relations may come up and be viewed as a basis for estimation. But also, we can look at such relations with a practical eye and wonder:
Your equation of a product of two expected values, in order to equal zero requires

Either that at least one of them is equal to zero - then why use also the other one?

or it can also hold true if

Both of them equal zero, so again, why not use just one of them?

